# Yii2 Blank page while upload file with .php extension

Tags: php, file, upload, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a problem when uploading a file with a .php file extension. The problem is becoming blank pages and unsuccessfully redirected to index (files uploaded but the page is blank)

This does not happen when I use other extension files (jpeg, jpg, txt, doc, docx etc).

Ps. I am using Oracle as database and using yii2 UploadedFile

Here my model

```
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'JOB';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['JOBNAME', 'CLASS', 'ACTION', 'SCHEDULE', 'STATUS'], 'required'],
        [['ID', 'STATUS'], 'integer'],
        [['JOBNAME'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
        [['FILECOMMAND'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'jpeg, php, txt'],
        [['CLASS', 'ACTION', 'SCHEDULE'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['ID'], 'unique'],
    ];
}
```

}

Here my controller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $scheduleList = yii::$app->params['cronparam'];
    $model = new JOB();
    if (yii::$app->request->post()) {
        $state = true;
        $data = yii::$app->request->post()['JOB'];
        try {
            $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
            $model->JOBNAME = $data['JOBNAME'];
            $model->CLASS = $data['CLASS'];
            $model->ACTION = $data['ACTION'];
            $model->SCHEDULE = $data['SCHEDULE'];
            $model->STATUS = $data['STATUS'];
            $model->files = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'FILECOMMAND');
            $model->FILECOMMAND = $model->files;
            $model->files->saveAs(yii::getAlias('@app') . yii::$app->params['pathJobFile'] . $model->files->baseName . '.' . $model->files->extension, false);

            if (!$model->save()) {
                $ErrorMessage = $model->getErrorMessage($model->getErrors());
                throw new Exception($ErrorMessage);
            }
            $message = "Success insert Job " . ucwords($model->JOBNAME);
            $transaction->commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $message = $e->getMessage();
            $state = false;
            $transaction->rollBack();
        }
        if ($state) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('SuccessJob', $message);
            $this->redirect('index');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('ErrorJob', $message);
            $this->render('create', ['scheduleList' => $scheduleList, 'model' => $model]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', ['scheduleList' => $scheduleList, 'model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return` statements here:

```
 if ($state) {
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('SuccessJob', $message);
    return $this->redirect('index');  //here
 } else {
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('ErrorJob', $message);
    return $this->render('create', ['scheduleList' => $scheduleList, 'model' => $model]); //and here
 }
```

Comment: after i write that up, problem still comes when uploading with php extension file, the solution is adding 'checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false in model